# How can I include a CreateView template in a ListView?

Tags: python, django

I want to make my blog like Facebook, where the option to create a post is in the same view as the list of posts.

I'm trying to include the CreateView template in my ListView, but it gives me this error:

```
Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.
```

I also tried to use the same method in comments. Does this method work or is there another way?

This is the `post_list.html` template:

```
{% extends "posts/post_base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% block post_content %}

  <div class="col-md-6">
    {% for post in post_list %}

       {% include "posts/_post.html" %}
       {% inclide 'posts/_create_post.html %}

    {% endfor %}
   </div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the `create_post.html` template:

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<form  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    <input type="submit" name="" value="comment">
</form>
```

What I want to do is just include the create template inside list template. If this will not work, I just want to let the user create a new post on the same page as the list of posts like Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your ListView you need to add the form

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    ctx['form'] = myForm(self.request.POST or None)
    return ctx
```

Then you should be able to use in the template

Comment: gives me this error "request' is not defined" this means what?

Comment: use self.request instead of request